# Handle Interrupt and retry in Ruby until .. do loop

Tags: ruby, loops

Is it possible to handle a SIGINT within an `until .. do` loop and continue to the next iteration? I have only been able to find examples of doing this within `for` loops and functions.
I tried (from an example)

```rb
test = "hey"
until test == "hi" do
        test = gets.chomp
end rescue retry
```

but this simple exited when I pressed ctrl+c. I also get an error when I place the `rescue` within the block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I just needed to wrap the loop inside a `begin .. end`

```rb
test = "hey"
begin
        until test == "hi" do
               test = gets.chomp
        end
rescue Interrupt
        retry
end
```

Comment: Note that this will start a new loop each time (not a problem, just saying). If this isn't desired, you can also move the whole `begin ... rescue ... end` structure _inside_ the loop. And instead of `retry` (which runs the `begin` block again), you could also use `next` to move to the loop's next iteration or `redo` to redo the current iteration (equivalent for `until` but quite different for enumerators yielding elements).

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for the info. I assume `retry` would result in variables being set to their state at the start of that loop iteration, while `next` would preserve changes?

Comment: It changes the point of re-entrance: `retry` goes back to the beginning of the `begin` body whereas `next` (or `redo`) goes back to the beginning of the loop's body. Whether a variable gets reset depends on the scope it is defined in (outside the loop / inside the loop but before `begin` / within `begin` etc.) It's probably more a matter of semantics – do you want to `retry` the operation that previously failed with an exception, or do you just want to carry on with the `next` iteration in case of an exception?

Comment: The context is a shell program. The idea is that pressing control+c should cancel the current operation/ask to confirm exiting rather than immediately exit. With the program architecture I suspect the outcome is the same, thanks